# Android notifications as natural language voice, not sounds

Tags: android

I am fed up with trying to remember what the various beeps from my 'phone mean.

Is the an app which will use a voice synthesizer (or recorded voice) to tell me what just happened?

I.E "you've got mail", "BBC breaking news", "time to play poker", etc

Comment: That would be the thing! For about a year I try to figure what app is causing a certain "noise", as it doesn't even leave a notification. I'd already welcome something like "this noise was presented to you by…" (to be enabled when needed, of course). // That said: gratis/libre, or some price limit? Android version to be covered (aka "minSDK")? For your case, [SpeakMe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flip.speakme) might work – but hasn't been updated for years. Or [Notification Speaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bhkapps.shouter).

Comment: PS: found you some more potential candidates. As usual, in [my corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_notifications#group_543). Haven't checked any of them, so feel free to self-answer if one of them fits! I just wonder why most of them use Firebase, and what for…

Comment: Thanks, as always, Izzy. I am looking for a new project at the moment. If there is no good match, perhaps I will code one :-)

Comment: If you do the latter, please make it F/LOSS and let me know when it's ready for my repo or F-Droid's – and then to be added to my lists :-)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a01QQZyl-_I     ;-)